# Merging google sheets: match with specific col values and merge data in 2 different sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I would like to ask if there is any possible way to set up a simple version of app script that is similar to the below add-ons.

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/merge-sheets/gdmgbiccnalapanbededmeiadjfbfhkl?utm_source=ablebits

Basically, I've got sheet 1 and sheet 3, both sheets will have a common key column with specific values in each cell, and I would like to map both sheets with the data in that column then update the whole row data in the other sheets (For example, if i updated the sheet 3 then it map that col value in sheet 1, then paste the data in the corresponding row)

I have came up with a code that runs but no changes have been made, could anyone please advise how can I modify it to a simple version similar to the above add-ons? Thanks in advance.

I would like to populate the date from sheet 3 to sheet 1 after the code run, while the data from col C is matched in both sheets, please see example below, thanks!

For example, the data in sheet 1 highlighted row is having its key col with col C for common lookup value with sheet 3 while the row sequence is diff with sheet 3 (Please see the next photo, thanks!)

[image]

As you can see in sheet 3, the data of the whole row is inserted to the correct row according to the col C key col value which matched with sheet 1.

[image]

```
function myFunction2(){
    // Get your spreadsheet and the sheets "TB" and "2"
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheet1 = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet 1");
    var sheet3 = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet 3");

    // Get the range on sheet "TB"
    var tabsheet1 = sheet1.getRange(2, 2, sheet1.getLastRow(), 
    sheet1.getLastColumn());

    // Get the values to compare
    var datasheet1 = tabsheet1.getValues();
    var datasheet3 = sheet3.getRange(2, 2, sheet3.getLastRow(), sheet3.getLastColumn());

    for(var i = 0; i < datasheet1.length; i++){

        for(var j = 0; j < datasheet3.length; j++){

            // Compare data: if they're the same, put the value 
            if(datasheet1[i][0]=(datasheet3[j][0]) == 0){

                //if(datasheet1[i][0].localeCompare(datasheet3[j][0]) == 0){

                datasheet1[i][1] = datasheet3[j][1];
            }
        }
    }

    // Take the modified tab and put it on the spreadsheet
    tabsheet1.setValues(datasheet1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to copy the data of sheet 3 to sheet 1. For this situation, when the values of column C of sheet 3 and sheet 1 is the same, you want to copy the row of sheet 3 to sheet 1, because the order of rows for sheet 3 and sheet 1 are different. If my understanding is correct, how about this modification?

#### Modification points :

- In order to retrieve the values from column C to last column, it uses `getRange(2, 3, sheet1.getLastRow(), sheet1.getLastColumn())`.
- In your script, `datasheet3` is the range.
- About `if(datasheet1[i][0]=(datasheet3[j][0]) == 0){`, in order to comare the date, I used `getDisplayValues()`.

  - By this, the values retrieved as a string are compared.

#### Modified script :

```
function myFunction2(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet1 = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet 1");
  var sheet3 = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet 3");
  var tabsheet1 = sheet1.getRange(2, 3, sheet1.getLastRow(), sheet1.getLastColumn());
  var datasheet1 = tabsheet1.getValues();
  var datasheet1d = tabsheet1.getDisplayValues(); // Added
  var tabsheet3 = sheet3.getRange(2, 3, sheet3.getLastRow(), sheet3.getLastColumn()); // Added
  var datasheet3 = tabsheet3.getValues(); // Modified
  var datasheet3d = tabsheet3.getDisplayValues(); // Added
  for (var i = 0; i < datasheet1.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < datasheet3.length; j++) {
      if (datasheet1d[i][0] == datasheet3d[j][0]) { // Modified
        datasheet1[i] = datasheet3[j]; // Modified
      }
    }
  }
  tabsheet1.setValues(datasheet1);
}
```

#### Reference :

- [getDisplayValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getDisplayValues())

If I misunderstand your question, please tell me. I would like to modify it. At that time, in order to modify, can you share the sample sheet? Of course, please remove your private information from it.

### Edit 1 :

```
function myFunction2(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet1 = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet 1");
  var sheet3 = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet 3");
  var tabsheet1 = sheet1.getRange(2, 3, sheet1.getLastRow() - 1, sheet1.getLastColumn() - 2); // Modified
  var datasheet1 = tabsheet1.getValues();
  var datasheet1d = tabsheet1.getDisplayValues(); // Added
  var tabsheet3 = sheet3.getRange(2, 3, sheet3.getLastRow() - 1, sheet3.getLastColumn() - 2); // Added
  var datasheet3 = tabsheet3.getValues(); // Modified
  var datasheet3d = tabsheet3.getDisplayValues(); // Added
  for (var i = 0; i < datasheet1.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < datasheet3.length; j++) {
      if (datasheet1d[i][0] == datasheet3d[j][0]) { // Modified
        datasheet3[j].push(""); // Modified
        datasheet1[i] = datasheet3[j]; // Modified
      }
    }
  }
  tabsheet1.setValues(datasheet1);
}
```

### Edit 2 :

```
function myFunction2(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet1 = ss.getSheetByName("comment_log");
  var sheet3 = ss.getSheetByName("CM");
  var tabsheet1 = sheet1.getRange(2, 3, sheet1.getLastRow() - 1, sheet1.getLastColumn() - 2); // Modified
  var datasheet1 = tabsheet1.getValues();
  var datasheet1d = tabsheet1.getDisplayValues(); // Added
  var tabsheet3 = sheet3.getRange(2, 3, sheet3.getLastRow() - 1, sheet3.getLastColumn() - 2); // Added
  var datasheet3 = tabsheet3.getValues(); // Modified
  var datasheet3d = tabsheet3.getDisplayValues(); // Added
  for (var i = 0; i < datasheet1.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < datasheet3.length; j++) {
      if (datasheet1d[i][0] == datasheet3d[j][0]) { // Modified
        if (datasheet1[i].length != datasheet3[j].length) {
          for (var k = 0; k < datasheet1[i].length - datasheet3[j].length; k++) {
            datasheet3[j].push(datasheet1[i][datasheet1[i].length - 1]);
          }
        }
        datasheet1[i] = datasheet3[j]
      }
    }
  }
  tabsheet1.setValues(datasheet1);
}
```

Comment: Hi Tanaike, thanks for your reply! Yes yes, I would like to copy the whole row data from sheet 3 to sheet 1 only if the data col value matches while sheet 1 and sheet 3 row order maybe diff and the row no. may change (sheet1 may have more rows than sheet 3, this is due to my sheet 1 will be the master of facebook comment webhook which flows in automatically and sheet 3 is the sheet that i use to edit then sync is back to sheet 1)

Comment: However, when I run the code, it said "Incorrect range width, was 21 but should be 24 (line 18)"

Please also have the below link for the template sheet for your reference:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1MEo-KnqL4sgBsvcRp2oyPkVUNtugy_9Z7KNSrMWgO7Q/edit?usp=sharing

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: @Nicola Hoo I'm sorry for the inconvenience. From your question, I had thought that the number of columns of both sheet 3 and sheet 1 is the same. But from your shared sheet, it was found that it is different. This is my mistake that I couldn't notice about it. So I updated my answer. Please confirm it.

Comment: @Nicola Hoo Was my answer useful for you? If you have issues in my answer, feel free to tell me. Such information helps me to study. Also I think that it helps other users to know the situation as an information.

Comment: Hi Tanaike, thanks for your prompt response! I tried with the edited one and got an error '' Incorrect range width, was 21 but should be 22 (line 20, file "Testing")", could you please advise, thanks!!!

Comment: And I've tried to applied the code in another 2 sheets (Please see in the template sheet), comment_log = sheet 1 and CM = sheet 3, and trying to compare the col R (string of raw data instead of the col c time) but it keep saying the range width was wrong. Please kindly take a look into the script in the sheet, thanks a lot!!

Comment: @Nicola Hoo I'm really sorry for the inconvenience. I updated my answer. Please confirm it.

Comment: @Nicola Hoo Was my answer useful for you? If you have issues for my answer yet, feel free to tell me. I would like to study to solve your issues.

Comment: Hello Tanaike, sorry for the late reply, I've tried your code, but it seem like it is still using the col c time as the key col to match between 2 sheets, if i removed the time in col c, its not working.

Comment: @Nicola Hoo I'm sorry for the inconvenience. Can I ask you about your current detail situation? I couldn't understand your situation. If you can do, please add it to your question. I'm really sorry for my poor English skill.

Comment: Hi Tanaike, thanks for your help in advance!! I have add my data in the sheet cm and comment_log (highlighted for your ref), I am trying to match the data in col Q, like if the col Q data  on cm sheet is matching with in the comment_log sheets. It will sync all other row data back to the comment log. Please take a look at https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1MEo-KnqL4sgBsvcRp2oyPkVUNtugy_9Z7KNSrMWgO7Q/edit#gid=1368971349. Thanks!

Comment: oh i think i managed to use your edited code by changing the (2,3, last row, last col) to (2,1,last row, last col). Thanks!!!

Comment: @Nicola Hoo Thank you for your additional information. Can I think that your issue was solved? I'm sorry for my poor English skill.

Comment: @Nicola Hoo Did my answer show you the result that you want? Would you please tell me about it? That is also useful for me to study. If this works, other people who have the same issue as you can also base your question as a question that can be solved. If you have issues with my answer yet, I apologize. At that time, can I ask you about your current situation? I would like to study to solve your issues.