# Compare two sheets and append new data

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Long time user, first time caller. I recently made and account and am loving the help this site provides so I thought I would look for some of my own.

So I have been able to parse the two sheets ("Grab" and "Copy"), and update dates that have changed. ("Grab" gathers *new* data and is copied to "Copy" which is where the email script lies). It checks the rows for matching data and updates the rest of the row with any new data.  But I cannot figure out how to get new rows from "Grab" to move to "Copy". *the code below takes the ranges in grab and copies any differences to the Copy sheet.*

**Is there a way to append the new data to "Copy"? If a new row appears in the grab, append it to the Copy sheet. **

Here is a link to a sheet that is very similar to my setup:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1kdn48lel-0er6ACZRjxSUHgYJQobDj2nHrnFq2G2Hm8/edit?usp=sharing

The code that checks and fixes data is in the script editor of that sheet, but I will also post it below.

```
function mergeData()
{
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet1 = ss.getSheetByName("Copy");
  var sheet2 = ss.getSheetByName("Grab");
  var rangeSheet1 = sheet1.getRange(3, 1, sheet1.getLastRow() + 1, sheet1.getLastColumn() -7);
  var dataSheet1 = rangeSheet1.getValues();
  var displaySheet1 = rangeSheet1.getDisplayValues();
  var rangeSheet2 = sheet2.getRange(2, 1, sheet2.getLastRow(), sheet2.getLastColumn());
  var dataSheet2 = rangeSheet2.getValues();
  var displaySheet2 = rangeSheet2.getDisplayValues();

  for (var i = 0; i < dataSheet1.length; i++)
   {
    for (var j = 0; j < dataSheet2.length; j++)
     {
      if (displaySheet1[i][0] == displaySheet2[j][0])
       {
        if (dataSheet1[i].length != dataSheet2[j].length)
         {
          for (var k = 0; k < dataSheet1[i].length - dataSheet2[j].length; k++)
           {
            dataSheet2[j].push(dataSheet1[i][dataSheet1[i].length - 1]);
          }
        }
        dataSheet1[i] = dataSheet2[j]
      }
    }
  }
  rangeSheet1.setValues(dataSheet1);
}
```

**How can I also add new rows to the "Copy" sheet?**

I have gotten this far by relying on these two answers, but neither seem to append new data:

[Update or Replace Row data in other sheet when unique id is found - Google Appscript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62547344/update-or-replace-row-data-in-other-sheet-when-unique-id-is-found-google-appsc)

[Merging google sheets: match with specific col values and merge data in 2 different sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49179452/merging-google-sheets-match-with-specific-col-values-and-merge-data-in-2-differ)

*these are Stackoverflow links, not external sources*

and I cant even vote them up because I dont have the rep :(

Thank you for your help. If I didn't provide enough info or didn't ask correctly, tell me. I'm new.

Comment: I'm sorry its quite confusing. You mentioned earlier that you have an existing code that compare 2 sheet and update the dates that has been changed. Then you are asking how to append new data added in your Grab sheet to your copy sheet? This is a separate functionality right? Another question, how do you trigger your mergeData()? Its quite complicated to use onEdit() trigger to check if a complete new row data is added so would it be ok to use custom menu to tigger the append function?

Comment: I tried to take a look at your code but your ranges are completely screwed up.  I don't think it's worth the bother.  If I can see your data then I'm not even going to try.  And oh by the way I don't follow links to external resources.

Comment: I edited my question for clarification. Ron, the code above checks all data in the first sheet and edits the second with new data (for example if a date were to change). The function will be triggered manually with an option button, that code is just not in here.  I figured with this already checking data then it could also add new rows. If it has to be a second function so be it. MetaMan, the ranges work to avoid the headers and to ignore columns wider than the starting sheet. The links above are Stack Overflow links, I apologize I didn't specify. Also, I'm sorry it's not worth the bother.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### You can check this sample code:

```
function mergeData()
{
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet1 = ss.getSheetByName("Copy");
  var sheet2 = ss.getSheetByName("Grab");
  var sheet1Header = 2;
  var sheet2Header = 1;
  var rangeSheet1 = sheet1.getRange(sheet1Header + 1, 1, sheet1.getLastRow() - sheet1Header);
  var displaySheet1 = rangeSheet1.getDisplayValues();
  var rangeSheet2 = sheet2.getRange(sheet2Header + 1, 1, sheet2.getLastRow() - sheet2Header, sheet2.getLastColumn());
  var displaySheet2 = rangeSheet2.getDisplayValues();
  Logger.log(displaySheet1);
  Logger.log(displaySheet2);

  displaySheet2.forEach( data => {

   Logger.log(data);
   var regNo = data[0];
   Logger.log(regNo);
   var textFinder = rangeSheet1.createTextFinder(regNo);
   var match = textFinder.findNext();
   if(match){
     Logger.log("UPDATE DATA");
     //Reg. No found in Copy Sheet, Update data
     sheet1.getRange(match.getRow(),1,1,data.length).setValues([data]);
     
   }
   else {
     //Add new Reg. No to Copy Sheet
     Logger.log("APPEND DATA");
     sheet1.appendRow(data);
   }
  });

}
```

- You can check the execution logs to further understand what the code does. You can remove it after if it is not necessary anymore.

### What it does?

1. Get the range of valid data (without header) in Copy Sheet Column A. We will use this range later to create a text finder.
2. Get the all the data without header in Grab Sheet. Set it to `displaySheet2` variable
3. Loop each row of data in `displaySheet2`. Check if current row's `regNo` data exists in `rangeSheet1` (The range we obtained in step 1) using [Range.createTextFinder(findText)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#createtextfinderfindtext). It will return a [TextFinder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/text-finder) obj, use [TextFinder.findNext()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/text-finder#findnext) to get the match range. If the current `regNo` string was not found in the range selected, it will return a `null` value.
4. If match was found, it will return a [Range](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range) pointing to the matched cell. Update the data in Copy Sheet by selecting the range based on the matched cell's row index.
5. If match was not found, append the current row data using [Sheet.appendRow(rowContents)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#appendrowrowcontents)

### Output:

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I needed it to do. I can play with the formatting part after it runs (for aesthetics of course). Thank you so much. I didn't even think about appendRow but that's why I'm here. 
Sorry I cant upvote it.

Comment: Glad to hear that. By the way. If we answered your question, please click the accept button.  By doing so, other people in the community, who may have the same concern as you, will know that theirs can be resolved. If the accept button is unavailable to you, feel free to tell me. [How to accept answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235)